# When is a static middleware file sent to the client, using node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a bit new to node and I'm trying to understand the req, res system and middleware.

By using this code:

```
app.use('/stylesheets', express.static('stylesheets'))
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

As the client request the page, is the external css document sent with the index.html or is it requested later as the client interprete the html file?

Hope its not a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When someone requests the `'/'` route, you send him and html file, and when the browsers interprets it, it will make css requests, which will be responded by the `('/stylesheets', express.static('stylesheets')` middleware

Comment: Okei :) Thank you!!

Comment: @HenningHolm, if an answer attends what you asked, is common practice to at least accept it =)

Comment: Okei, im sorry! I will remember that!